# autolayout preventing button from moving

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I posted a question wondering why my UIImages were staying in the same position as in the interface builder, despite me adding the

```
    self.non_image1_outlet.center = CGPoint(x: 211, y: 10)
    self.med_image2_outlet.center = CGPoint(x: 244, y: 10)
    self.image3_outlet.center = CGPoint(x: 277, y: 10)
```

I have switched from using images to buttons now. My issue was that no matter what CGPoints I put in the code above, the buttons would always go back to the same position as in the interface builder. I was not getting my desired position. I wanted the other buttons to move somewhere else when one of them is pressed, but again, auto layout is preventing this. The buttons quickly move to said position but "snap" back to place to the original location placed in the interface builder.

I got downvoted since I had lack of code, but i've figured out it isn't a code issue, rather auto layout. Disabling it from the file inspector, the button moved to where I wanted it to go. However, disabling auto layout messed up my whole main UI and caused a huge mess. Is there anyway to disable auto layout on a specific element rather than the whole project? The reason the button did not go to where the CGPoint specified is due to auto layout locking it in place despite me putting no constraints on it.

EDIT: Or just being able to move the UIButton to where I want it to go with auto layout active.

Comment: It is not preventing you from moving anything. You just aren't moving anything. If you bolt something down it won't move no matter how hard you push it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by re-adding proper constraints. Everything seems to works fine now.

If you are having the same issue I did, I suggest clearing all the current constraints and slowly adding the proper constraints one of by. Top, left, right, and bottom margin, as well as spacing to any other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make to `center` or `frame` will get reset the next time the auto layout engine does a pass.

To move your button, you either need to:

- Move the button by updating the `constant` value of your button's layout constraints
- Remove the layout constraints and set the button's position manually

Comment: That's the thing, there are no constraints on the button in the first place, yet it still locks in place due to auto layout. Thank you for your input, I appreciate it. I've been looking for a while now. It's just a simple button to move from one place to another. No constraints at all. Just it being placed in a custom cell is all.

Comment: @RandomDude, there are constraints. If you don't set up constraints for a view in a NIB that uses auto layout, Xcode will add them at build time. It tells you this on the Size inspector for that view. So, you really want to set up the constraints yourself, since the automatically generated ones probably won't do what you want in the long term. When you use auto layout, you really need to get into it. You can't just let things slide and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I appreciate it! I was sort of "letting it slide" since I wasn't concerned about constraints at the time due to adding content and functionality.